# Invalid UTF-8 data when using std::locale to format numbers in French

Tags: c++, utf-8, locale, std

I'm using the following code to format numbers using the proper locale. When using French, numbers have "non-breaking space" between groups of digits. The string I'm getting seems to be invalid.

```
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.imbue(std::locale("fr_FR.UTF-8"));
    ss << 1234;
    auto result = ss.str();
```

here, `result` is: `{49, -62, 50, 51, 52}`. The non-breaking space is represented with -62. It seems to me that it's invalid UTF-8, right?

I expect `result` to be: `{49, -62, -96, 50, 51, 52}` (in this case, this seems valid, with the non-breaking space represented with two chars: -62, -96).

Am I missing something? Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you check `result`?

Comment: @Some-programmer-dude Using the watch window of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `std::locale` doesn't support multi-byte digit separators because [`std::numpunct::thousands_sep`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct/thousands_sep) only returns a single code unit (`char` in this case). As a result, in your case, the digit separator NO-BREAK SPACE `0xC2 (-62) 0xA0 (-96)` gets truncated and you only see the first code unit `0xC2 (-62)` which is an invalid partial UTF-8.